# c# call dll to get continuous output

Tags: c#

I wrote a dll myself, the function is to continuously output the current time, but it will only output once when it is called. I don't know how to let the calling program continue to get the return data of the dll and output it. Possibly by calling the dll repeatedly, but I only want to call the dll once
console exe:

```
string path = @"ClassLibrary3.dll";
            Assembly assem = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
            Type[] tys = assem.GetTypes();
            foreach (Type ty in tys)
            {
                if (ty.Name == "Class1")
                {
                    ConstructorInfo magicConstructor = ty.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
                    object magicClassObject = magicConstructor.Invoke(new object[] { });
                    MethodInfo mi = ty.GetMethod("Output");
                    object aa = mi.Invoke(magicClassObject, null);
                    Console.WriteLine(aa.ToString());
                }
            }
```

DLl:

```
namespace ClassLibrary3
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public string Output()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                return Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(8).ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You `return` out of the `while` loop, that's why.

Comment: What do I need to do to achieve the same effect as return

Comment: If you want the dll to repeatedly call back to the application you should probably be using a delegate. Read up on those.

Comment: I know this is just prototype code, but could you elaborate on what you are actually trying to do? To me it looks like you might actually need multi-threading.

Comment: Your code is making an HTTP request/response.  You are getting a 500 status in the request.  There is something happening in the server that is causing issue.  Try adding a delay in the loop and see if you continue to get the 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be using [`yield return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield):

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> Output()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(8).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }        
}
```

...and then iterate over the return value:

```cs
// ...
MethodInfo mi = ty.GetMethod("Output");
var aa = (IEnumerable<string>)mi.Invoke(magicClassObject, null);

foreach (var a in aa)
    Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks for your help, but I have another problem, when loading remotely, the content is empty

Comment: this is my code please help me:https://anonfiles.com/l8j4k8E1y3/code_txt

Comment: @user11603749 what content? You should probably make another question for it. And to be honest, it's kinda sketchy that you are trying to post-load an assembly to execute. That's the stuff you would do when exploiting a vulnerability of a system. Not exclusively, of course, but it sends some red flags.